# Android prevent back key function from whole application

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have to prevent back key functionality in my android application whenever the back key is pressed. This should be applied for whole app. I'm new to android programming. Does someone can help me with some helpful code segment?

Comment: You've got a number of answers telling you how to do what you've asked, but I'd ask you to think carefully about whether what you're doing is appropriate -- unilaterally breaking the back button might really annoy your users.  Of course, there are times when it is appropriate but often you can re-think your workflow to allow the user to use their back button.  If you do disable it, at least provide feedback about why it's disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass Activity and Fragment and override `onBackPressed`. You cannot simply disable the back key globally.

Comment: So I have to override onBackPressed in each activity. anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, can't help it. Mark as accepted if it answers your question please :)

Comment: This is your first Stack Overflow question I see. Press "accept as answer". This will award reputation to the person who answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by Overriding `onBackPressed()`

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed(){
   // You can Customise your Back key Functionality Over here.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the onBackPressed event will do your work